# how can I dump all object names from javascript native?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to dump only obj names from `this` in google dev or firefox , but however I only want to dump `Array, document, etc` , however I tried this , but I am not expecting the `obj.prototype` how can I achieve this?

```
const getMethods = (obj) => {
  let properties = new Set()
  let currentObj = obj
  do {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(currentObj).map(item => properties.add(item))
  } while ((currentObj = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentObj)))
  return [...properties.keys()].filter(item => typeof obj[item] === 'function')
}

getMethods(document.prototype)


Object.getOwnPropertyNames(document.prototype)
```